# Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.BufferingHelper' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.1.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to upgrade my API project from .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.1. I get this exception while I try to make the API call.

> "Message":"Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.BufferingHelper' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.","Statuscode":500,"TrackingID":"800000bd-0000-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb"

I tried the solution on "[github](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore/issues/293)"

Please help me fix the issue.

Answer (score 10):

I know you already tried [this solution](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore/issues/293) <s>but I didn't understand what the post meant with</s> (See comment below)

> "By referencing the fixed dll instead of the NuGet package it works
>   again."

However:

My Azure Function was using `EnableRewind()` on the request object in order to make the stream seekable. I did a straight replace with `EnableBuffering()` and everything worked again.

I'm using Azure Functions v3 with .NET Core 3.1. This was the error I originally received:

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.BufferingHelper' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

Comment: "By referencing the fixed dell" there means that instead of using the latest nuget package at the time, they instead referenced a dll they built themselves that had a fix for their specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

So I had the exact issue by using the `ReadAsStringAsync` method. You will notice that the implementation of that uses the `EnableRewind` method as well. I ended up just making my own version of `ReadAsStringAsync`. Implementation is below:

```
public static async Task<string> ReadAsStringAsync(this HttpRequest request)
        {
            request.EnableBuffering();

            string result = null;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(
                request.Body,
                encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
                detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true,
                bufferSize: 1024,
                leaveOpen: true))
            {
                result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue during mvc project upgrade from .net core 2.1 to 3.1. Upgrade `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` to 3.1.22 through NuGet Package Manager, solved the issue.